# Passing checkbox true or false VueJS

Tags: vue.js

I have a checkbox on my VueJS site, I want to do the following: if the checkbox `special` is true, then send in database value `1` in column, how can I do this correctly?

I did like this:

```
<label class="checkbox-control">
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="special"  v-on:change="special"  :disabled="channel.length === 0">

  <div class="checkbox-control__content"><i></i>Test</div>
</label>

data() {
    return {
      channel: "",
      special: false,
    }
    sendFunction() {
      this.$root.axios.post("/user/userPromo", {
        channel: this.channel,
        special: this.special
      }).then((res) => {
        const data = res.data;
        this.$root.showNotify(data.type, this.$t(`index.${data.message}`, {
          name: data.name
        }));
      });
    },
```

And in backend when i add data in table, i use `$special = $r->get('special');`, but it doesn't want to work. When is my mistake?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use: `true-value="1" false-value="false"`

```
<input type="checkbox" v-model="toggle" true-value="1" false-value="false" />

// when checked:
vm.toggle === '1'
// when unchecked:
vm.toggle === 'false'
```

Vue2 and Vue3 :

https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#checkbox-2

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox

Then use `this.special` inside `methods` `sendFunction`:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    special: false
  },
  methods: {
    sendFunction: function(event) {
    
      console.log(this.special)
      
      //this.$root.axios.post("/user/userPromo", {
        //channel: this.channel,
        //special: this.special
      //}).then((res) => {
        //const data = res.data;
        //this.$root.showNotify(data.type, this.$t(`index.${data.message}`, {
          //name: data.name
        //}));
      //});
    }  
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="special" v-on:change="sendFunction" true-value="1" false-value="false">
</div>
```

Also if if `this.special` wont be available inside axios it means `this` will be bound to axios function so you need to save data before and use it inside as saved variable:

```
 sendFunction: function(event) {
        const value = this.special      
          this.$root.axios.post("/user/userPromo", {
          //use value here
```